# Download multiple files: DownloadManager or AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-download-manager

I'm developing an app that allow user to download multiple podcasts files from a website, and i have some doubt about "how" show downloading progress to user.
For now, my app is just composed by a single activity that show a list of available files, and when user tap an element, i launch DownloadManager. 
I obtain a better use experience by keep DonwloadManager (and signal in some way, for example by changing color of downloaded file, the end of download), or is better use AsyncTasks and show Donwloading progress inside a separate view (for example a fragment that show a progressbar for each downloading file)?

Comment: `use AsyncTasks and show Donwloading progress` you can also use downloadmanager to show progressDialog.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use **DownloadManager** that will be better to download the multiple files. You can set the request in queue and your file will be downloading even if your app is not running. If something goes wrong i.e. lost the connectivity, it will resume the downloading whenever you will get connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the **DownloadManager** class downloads one file at a time but allows you to queue multiple files. It also managers stuff like loss of connectivity etc which is really useful. Using **DownloadManager** you can also make calls to progress of the files using the **DownloadManager.request**.

The advantage of using an AsyncTask is the methods that come with it - namely onPostExecute, onPreExecute, onProgressUpdate and doInBackground. You can have a callback telling your UI thread to update a progress bar. Also using an AsyncTask as your download service would allow multiple file downloads at once rather then queueing the downloads.

I hope this helps.